# How to redirect application from https://example.com to https://www.example.com/locale in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, redirect, next.js, middleware, next.js13

I have an application in next.js 13 (App Dir) where I have different locales such as /ae and /pk.

when in production, I want to redirect application to https://www. if no www. is written.

Currently I have this middleware for redirecting to locales.

| User Input | Current Behavior | Expected Behavior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `example.com` | `https://example.com/ae` | `https://www.example.com/ae` |

```
export async function middleware(request) {
const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;
const pathnameHasLocale = i18n.locales.some(
    (locale) => pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) || pathname === `/${locale}`
);

if (pathnameHasLocale) return;

const defaultLocale = "ae";

request.nextUrl.pathname = `/${defaultLocale}${pathname}`;

return Response.redirect(request.nextUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code snippet inside your middleware. It basically checks your route to see if it includes any of your defined locales, and if it cannot find any it will redirect to your default locale.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
const languages = ["ae","pk"] // add any other languages your app supports

// Redirect if lng in path is not supported
if (
   !languages.some((loc) => req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${loc}`)) &&
   !req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/_next")
){
return NextResponse.redirect(
   new URL(`/${defaultLocale}${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url)
)}
```